# what is struts2 serilaization

Tags: java, json, struts2

I am trying to implement struts2-jquery-grid. But I am stuck with the serialization issue. I can't find out really what is mean by serialization in struts2 `type="json"`. I have checked the struts website documentation but that is not clear to me. Anyone please tell me in simple words what is struts serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serialization is the process of converting a data structure or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and "resurrected" later in the same or another computer environment.

So JSON plugin is converting your whole object graph, starting on the action class and will send the data to the UI where the JSON data can be used for UI display and same process can be used in reverse order.

Concept of serialization is not specific to Struts2 its a generic concept and is used a lot in real life application

Answer (score 1):

The output of whatever object will be serialized into JSON format and returned to the client (web browser mostly in this case).

For example, if a class like such would to be returned in JSON:

```
class Person{
    private int age;
    private String name;
    // omitted getter and setter
}
```

Its corresponding JSON return String will be: (values are mocked up and assumed)

```
{"person1": {"age": "2", "name": "Chin Boon"}}
```